# Grunt async quits before done

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

```
grunt.registerTask('async-test',function(){
  console.log('async start')
  var done = this.async()
})
```

And as you can see, it just starts and immediately quits

[image]

Comment: But you're doing nothing after turning the task into an async task... try to call a `setTimeout` of 3 seconds and call `done()` as part of `setTimeout` callback, and before whe so-called `done()` log something to the console..

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer this is just a test. I want it to hang indefinitely.

Comment: There's nothing (in terms of _real_ pending async tasks) that is preventing Node from exiting the process.